# How to enable Show on Lock Screen permission by default

Tags: android, permissions, xiaomi

My app needs to display activity over the lock screen, And that is not working particularly on xiaomi devices, After some research I found that there is need to enable **Show On Lock Screen** permission.

I found that some of the applications on play store has this permission enabled by default,I have done lots of research but not found anyway of doing the same, Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me, give it a try

```
    <activity
            android:name=".activities.alarm"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            ></activity>
```